# Observable not returning the updated value

Tags: angular, async-await, observable, behaviorsubject

I would like to return a BehaviorSubject with the updated value that is updated from another function.

Making the other function async didn't work.

It threw an empty array - not the updated observable as the async didn't work.

The function that returns the BehaviorSubject to the component:

```js
getFilteredEvents(): BehaviorSubject<SummerEvent[]> {
  return this._filteredEvents$;
}
```

The function that calls getPosts2() and assigns the updated value to filteredEvents$

```js
async query3(): Promise<void> {
    const ans = await this.httpService.getPosts2();
    ans.subscribe( (response:any) => {
      var unfilteredEvents: SummerEvent[] = this.httpService.getSummerEvents(response)
      unfilteredEvents = this.getFutureSummerEvents(unfilteredEvents); 
      this._events$.next(unfilteredEvents); 
      var filteredEvents: SummerEvent[] = [];
      filteredEvents = this.setFilterByCity(this._events$.getValue());
      filteredEvents = this.getInitSortedPosts(filteredEvents);
      this._filteredEvents$.next(this.values);    
    }
}
```

The function getPosts2() that does http.get

```js
public async getPosts2(): Promise<any>{
  const data = this.http.get(this.POST_URL);
  return data;
}
```

Comment: If you declare the behaviorSubject in a class, you can access it in all your methods inside the class and by subscribing to the behaviorSubject you can get the data. I'd prefer using rxJs observables instead of async await.

Comment: private _filteredEvents$ = new BehaviorSubject <SummerEvent[]>([]);
 is declared and you can see it's use with .next in query3().  Any other idea why can't I read this BehaviorSubject as an empty array although Iv'e updated it on query3()? Should I remove

Comment: When you subscribe to the behaviourSubject, it will wait for data to be emitted. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/subject-and-behavior-subject-in-angular-8/


`getPosts2(): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get(this.POST_URL);
}`
Change the data fetching method to return an `Observable<T>`. HTTP get method by default return an `Observable<T>`. Also, you can remove the async await in the method you've declared.  `getSummerEvents` is supposed to not return BehaviorSubject as you're storing the data coming from `getPost2()`. So change it to return `SummerEvent[]`.